# WooCommerce Always Include Shipping Information in Checkout

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I have virtual products in my store but I still want to collect the shipping information from my customers so that I can mail them a card at the end of the year. But a cart with virtual products automatically hides the shipping information on the checkout page.

How can I force the shipping fields to show up? Is there a hook I can use?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually pretty easy. You just have to add this snippet to your `functions.php` file.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping', '__return_true' );
```